# Decryption with RSA_SSLV23_PADDING not working

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I am using openssl and trying to decrypt data which is encrypted using `RSA_SSLV23_PADDING`. The code is as follows:

```
BIO *pBPK=NULL;
RSA *pPrivKey;
pBPK = BIO_new_mem_buf ( ( void* ) strKey, -1 );
pPrivKey = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey ( pBPK, NULL, NULL, NULL );   
int flen = RSA_size ( pPrivKey );
unsigned char* from = (unsigned char*)strData;
int maxSize = RSA_size ( pPrivKey );
unsigned char* to = new unsigned char[maxSize];
int res = RSA_private_decrypt ( flen, from, to, pPrivKey, RSA_SSLV23_PADDING );
```

But I am always getting `res` as `-1`. When I use `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING`   or `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` then it works fine.

Comment: How do you know the data was encrypted with RSA_SSLV23_PADDING?  What do you mean by _"When I use RSA_PKCS1_PADDING or RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING then it works fine."_?  What is _"works fine"_?

Comment: I am actually creating a framework which does all this encryption-decryption. I take padding scheme as parameter and use it. When I supply RSA_PKCS1_PADDING or RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING then it works fine but when I supply RSA_SSLV23_PADDING it fails in decryption. During encrytion RSA_public_encrypt() doesn't return -1 but the length. So I am assuming it is working.

Comment: "works fine" here means I am able to retrieve the original data from encrypted text

Answer (score 0):

> Decryption with RSA_SSLV23_PADDING not working

That's a padding scheme used for rollback-attack detection in SSLv3 and above. Its meant to be used in the context of SSL/TLS.

> When I use `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING` or `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` then it works fine.

Right, these are modern RSA padding schemes.

---

> `int res = RSA_private_decrypt ( flen, from, to, pPrivKey, RSA_SSLV23_PADDING );`

To use `RSA_SSLV23_PADDING`, I believe you call `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding` on the `EVP_PKEY_CTX*`. See [`EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl.html) man pages for details.

---

You should probably avoid `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING`, and use `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`. For reading, see [A bad couple of years for the cryptographic token industry](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/06/bad-couple-of-years-for-cryptographic.html).